# How do I put an end to the endless loop in my assembly language program

Tags: assembly, x86, infinite-loop, cpu-architecture

I was asked to write a program that asks the user to enter their name, an integer, and another integer, add the two integers and then display the sum. The program is supposed to do this three times, clear the screen after each iteration and locate the cursor in the middle of the screen. The program only locates the cursor in the middle of the screen for the first question and also loops endlessly. Please help correct the code.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
  prompt1 BYTE "Enter Your Name:",0
  var1 byte 20 DUP(?)
  bytecount DWORD ?

  prompt BYTE "Enter Integer:",0
  resultMsg BYTE "Sum of the two integers is:",0
  Int1 DWORD ?
  Int2 DWORD ?
  Sum  DWORD ?

.code
main PROC

  MOV ECX,3


L1:
  call Clrscr
  ;Move cursor to the middle of the screen

  MOV DH,13
  MOV DL,40
  CALL GoToXY

  MOV EDX,OFFSET prompt1
  Call WriteString
  MOV EDX,OFFSET var1
  MOV ECX,sizeof var1
  Call ReadString


  MOV EDX, OFFSET prompt
  CALL WriteString
  CALL ReadInt
  MOV Int1,EAX

  CALL WriteString
  CALL ReadInt
  MOV Int2,EAX

  ;Calculate Sum

  MOV EAX,Int1
  ADD EAX,Int2
  MOV Sum,EAX

  ;display sum

  MOV EDX, OFFSET resultMsg
  call WriteString
  MOV EAX,Sum
  call WriteInt

  call Crlf
  call WaitMsg
  loop L1
  exit

main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: `MOV ECX,sizeof var1` overwites `ecx` which is your loop counter.

Comment: Thank you, the loop ends after three iterations now